# Problem with wifi drivers ubuntu 20.04 lts on BCM4360 802.11ac [14e4:43a0] (rev 3)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, live-usb, broadcom, macbook-pro

I  know there is a lot of threads about this, but I followed a great number of them and none worked.

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on a live usb using rufus for a mackbook pro late 2013. After a while, I noticed the driver is there by default, but : it only works once. Here is how I made it work once : I made the install by clicking the icon on the desktop up to the part where it asks where to make the install -> wifi worked until reboot. An other way was to go on the additional driver panel, disable it, reboot, enable it -> wifi worked until reboot.

I dont know why it is there and doesnt work...

[Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iph4J.png)

I also tried the b43 firmware installer, following other threads, but nothing worked.

Suggested commands in ubuntu 20.04.3 lts:

```
lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl  
wl                   6455296  0
cfg80211              888832  1 wl
```

And

```
grep -e b43 -e wl /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

And

```
    sudo dmesg | grep wl
    [   59.790911] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
    [   59.790920] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
    [   59.793410] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

And

```
sudo dmesg | grep -e wl -e bcma
[    1.141227] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x00
[    1.141271] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x2B, class 0x0)
[    1.141296] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x2A, class 0x0)
[    1.141342] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 2 found: ARM CR4 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83E, rev 0x02, class 0x0)
[    1.141392] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 3 found: PCIe Gen2 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83C, rev 0x01, class 0x0)
[    1.141417] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 4 found: USB 2.0 Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x81A, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[    1.196936] bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
[    1.197064] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
[    1.197070] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
[    1.197075] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: No SPROM available
[    1.200300] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Bus registered
[   45.291300] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   45.291307] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   45.293675] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

And

```
journalctl -b | grep bcma
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x00
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x2B, class 0x0)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x2A, class 0x0)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 2 found: ARM CR4 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83E, rev 0x02, class 0x0)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 3 found: PCIe Gen2 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83C, rev 0x01, class 0x0)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 4 found: USB 2.0 Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x81A, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: No SPROM available
déc 19 19:11:03 ubuntu kernel: bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Bus registered
```

Debug script log : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZhR4QRSpDp/

Commands done in 21.10 :

The driver was at first not enabled in the additional drivers window. I enabled it, worked fine until reboot. Then, I tried remove bcma, just in case, but nothing changed.

```
sudo dmesg | grep bcma
[    1.496684] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x00
[    1.496731] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x2B, class 0x0)
[    1.496757] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x2A, class 0x0)
[    1.496802] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 2 found: ARM CR4 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83E, rev 0x02, class 0x0)
[    1.496851] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 3 found: PCIe Gen2 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83C, rev 0x01, class 0x0)
[    1.496876] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 4 found: USB 2.0 Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x81A, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[    1.555428] bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
[    1.555512] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
[    1.555515] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
[    1.555518] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: No SPROM available
[    1.559096] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Bus registered
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl` and also: `grep -e b43 -e wl /etc/modprobe.d/* ` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, I updated it

Comment: Please reboot when the wireless is *not* working and show us the result again.

Comment: @chili555 the wireless was not working when I dit it and still does not, it only worked once. Currently I only have bluetooth (and internet via my phone ´s hotspot via Bluetooth).

Comment: Let's see the log: `sudo dmesg | grep wl` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 I updated it

Comment: I see nothing that provides a clue as to the problem. Let's have a full diagnostic report. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: @chili555 I added the link to the post

Comment: It's very interesting that: although it is blacklisted because it is incorrect for your device. the module *bcma* still loads. Please do: `sudo modprobe -r bcma` and then post: `sudo dmesg | grep -e wl -e bcma`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks a lot for your help, I updated it.

Comment: May we see: `journalctl -b | grep bcma`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, added.

Comment: Please try a live session of Ubuntu 21.10 and see if the issue persists: `sudo dmesg | grep bcma`

Comment: @chili555 Still not working, added result in the post.

Comment: I have researched this extensively: "Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card" I haven't found any solution. I regret that I haven't any other suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: @chili555 thanks a lot for your help, I hope I will manage to make it work

Comment: @chili555 Just so I can continue my own research, what is the correct driver to use and is "invalid SPROM" the main issue ?

Comment: @chili555 I added a solution to the thread. Thanks a lot for all your help, your questions helped me discover what the issue was. Do you know how to blacklist the wrong drivers so they dont launch on boot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How I made it (kinda) work

After a lot of trouble, I think I found a temporary solution.

On Ubuntu 21.10

### Step 1 :

On the driver manager -> additional driver -> enable Broadcom 802.11 bcmwl-kernel-source

Works until reboot.

### Step 2 (After reboot)

Wifi not working, probably because of drivers conflict.
Disable all drivers:

```
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe -r bcma
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac
```

After this, try one by one to enable them :

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

This is the one that works for me.

#### Problem

I have to do this after every reboot, because those changes don't save. I know there are .conf files with blacklist options, but I don't know which one to change.

Comment: How many of those modules are loaded on a fresh boot? b43? ssb? etc. Check: `lsmod`

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to this one but I got this to work by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
(Although you could probably make your own blacklist file if you fancy) with the following line:

```
blacklist bcma
```

as per @Infamous Jox above i discovered that doing `modprobe -r bcma wl` then `modprobe wl` would get it working.

You'll also need to run

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

for the blacklist to take effect.