# No Wifi-Adapter Found - Ubuntu 20.04.03 on USB with Persistent Storage

Tags: wireless, kernel, macbook-pro

I'm new to Ubuntu so apologies if I am asking obvious questions or need things explained very simply.

I created a USB Memory Stick with Ubuntu on it. I used a How To guide to create one with persistent storage (which I am very happy with as I am not technically-minded!). https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

I can't access Wifi for some reason - it says No Wifi Adapter Found. I am on a MacBook Pro and have no issues accessing Wifi when I boot using MacOS.

I have tried some solutions already. I navigated to Additional Drivers and it says I have Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source.

I tried opening the terminal and doing the following, but it didn't help:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 261 not to upgrade.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 261 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/1,546 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3 [1,546 kB]
(Reading database ... 234583 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-27-generic 5.11.0-43-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.11.0-27-generic
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.11.0-43-generic
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media
```

Is this something to do with the last line about being read-only media? It does have persistent memory as I can still see the same downloads after rebooting.

Thanks so much for your help.

Edit (as requested):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0112]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SS9183 PCIe SSD Controller [1b4b:9183] (rev 14)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe wl && sudo dmesg | grep wl
[   10.198859] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   10.198867] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   10.202226] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Edit 2:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep bcma
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod grep bcma
Usage: lsmod
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep bcma
[    0.881994] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x00
[    0.882039] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x2B, class 0x0)
[    0.882064] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x2A, class 0x0)
[    0.882110] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 2 found: ARM CR4 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83E, rev 0x02, class 0x0)
[    0.882158] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 3 found: PCIe Gen2 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83C, rev 0x01, class 0x0)
[    0.882183] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Core 4 found: USB 2.0 Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x81A, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[    0.937872] bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
[    0.937991] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
[    0.937994] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
[    0.937997] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: No SPROM available
[    0.941667] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: bus0: Bus registered
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `sudo modprobe wl && sudo dmesg | grep wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have made these edits, and thank you!

Comment: Ahhh, the 4360. Let's also see: `lsmod | grep bcma` and `sudo dmesg | grep bcma`

Comment: Please see edit 2. :)

Comment: Please see this question. Still no permanent working solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382301/problem-with-wifi-drivers-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-bcm4360-802-11ac-14e443a0-rev?noredirect=1#comment2384900_1382301

Comment: That's a shame but this person's temporary solution seems to have worked and allowed me to connect to Wifi. Annoying that I may have to do it every time but oh well! Thanks for your help!

Comment: A persistent install is not much different from an ISO as most of the file system isn't persistent and changes to the kernel or drivers do not survive a reboot

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done most of the work already.

you just need to start the wifi using `modprobe wl`.

In case you update your kernels its pretty likely that you wifi driver will get uninstalled. For that,

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This will help you install the wifi driver required without any hassle and you will once again need to activate it.